# Using VBA to click on a link using documentID

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, automation

```html
<a title=Start a New Quote" class="primary-btn floatright nav-link" id="startNewQuote" href="/qps/getCreateQutoe">
```

I'm totally new to VBA and html (why am i working on this project huh?)  I've had partial success getting VBA to automate data entry on a website...very partial and can get logged in and click on a couple links.  I've used 'getElementByID' before in the code and it works, but when I try and click on the next link in the site it says object required and won't click on it.

Why did it work before in the code but not now?  each element has an html ID. And how can i make it work? I've included the html from the site and my code so far.TIA

[image]

```
Sub AUTOFILL()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.ally.com/dealer/"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
        
    Set doc = IE.document
        
    IE.document.getElementById("user").Value = "UserName"
    IE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "Password"
    IE.document.getElementById("processLogin").Click
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    IE.document.getElementsByTagName ("a")
    IE.document.querySelector("[data-track-name='Vehicle Protection Center']").Click
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
        
    IE.document.getElementById("startNewQuote").Click
       
End Sub
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek3GI.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek3GI.png%5D)

Comment: Sorry i'm having trouble getting the screen shot of the html to load.  When i do 'inspect element' is has the following; <a title="Start a New Quote" class="primary-btn floatright nav-link" id="startNewQuote" href="/qps/getCreateQuote">

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html. It is the icon with <> on it. Then step through your code with F8 and see if error goes away by slowly executing code line by line, It may be you need a longer wait before the .Click.

Comment: I stepped through and it still does not click on the last link, so I don't think it's the wait time.

Comment: Can you simply navigate with _ie.navigate2 ie.document.querySelector("#startNewQuote").href_ all on one line

Comment: That gives me the same 'Object Required' error

Comment: Doesn't appear to be in an iframe/frame so I would still be thinking maybe a longer wait is needed before attempting to click or some other action is required to generate the node/make visible

Comment: I tried expanding to wait time in the code to 10 and 20 seconds and I still get the error.  when the macro pauses I wait and try and resume the macro and it till says Object required.  I tried stepping through it w/ F8 again and giving the site plenty of time the load and nothing.....I don't see any Iframe/frame around it in the html either....I'm just stuck.

Comment: @Qharr you were right it had to do with the wait time.  Expanding the wait time how I had it didn't help though, with some help I added a loop while the link = nothing that seems to have done the trick!